# Using IAM Role within Hadoop-AWS module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hadoop, amazon-iam

I am using a library that internally uses the `hadoop-aws` module and uses [IAM Assumed Roles](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/assumed_roles.html) to connect to S3.

However, the documentation mentions the following:

```
The S3A connector supports assumed roles for authentication with AWS. 
A full set of login credentials must be provided, 
which will be used to obtain the assumed role and refresh it regularly.
```

Now, to configure the authentication mechanism, there is property `fs.s3a.assumed.role.credentials.provider` with a few possible values, but all of the values are based on top of credentials like `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` etc.
However, AWS recommends to use IAM Roles instead of access keys.

Is there a way to configure this S3 adapter using IAM Roles so that I do not need to define the access keys?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Provider. (if not tried already)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.AssumedRoleCredentialProvider
Property: fs.s3a.assumed.role.arn

Moreover, S3 Bucket Policy should allow.
Example:
{
"Sid": "xyz",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam:::role/xyz-role"
},
"Action": [
"s3:List*",
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:PutObjectAcl"
],
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:s3:::xyz-s3",
"arn:aws:s3:::xyz-s3/*"
]
}

Comment: I tried `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.AssumedRoleCredentialProvider` along with the role's ARN, but it still needs the credentials for the initial load, in the form of env-var or something similar. The S3 bucket policy is already present for that role I used.

Comment: I used `WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider` and it worked after providing role arn and a session name.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.html